# need to replace xslt sentance containing . (dot ) with white space

Tags: java, xml, xslt, text

**description/@text is having one sentence containing .dot i want to replace that with white space.**

```
            <xsl:call-template name="playByPlayJson">
                <xsl:with-param name="sequenceNumber" select="position()"/>

        <xsl:with-param name="summaryPhrase" select="description/@text"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="outs" select="@outs-aft"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="baseSit" select="@base-sit-aft"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="hasScored" select="@scored"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="hasOutOccured" select="@outs-aft - @outs-bef &gt; 0"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="inning" select="../inning/@number"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="inningHalves" select="substring(../inning/@half, 1, 1)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="awayScore" select="@vis-score"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="homeScore" select="@home-score"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="eventAt" select="$eventAt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="@id"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:if test="$eventAt = ''">
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Please show example input XML and desired output XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
<xsl:with-param name="summaryPhrase" select="translate(description/@text,'.',' ')"/>
```